# plot count of discrete data by date

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot2` and trying to plot a continuous histogram showing the evolution of reviews by date and rating.

My data set look like this:

```
        date rating reviews
1 2017-11-24      1 some text here
2 2017-11-24      1 some text here
3 2017-12-02      5 some text here
4 2017-11-24      3 some text here
5 2017-11-24      3 some text here
6 2017-11-24      4 some text here
```

What I want to get is something like this:

for `rating == 1`

```
        date    count
1  2017-11-24      2
2  2017-11-25      7
.
.
.
```

and so on for `rating == 2` and `3`

I've tried

```
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = rating), data = df) + geom_line()
```

but it gives me only rating on the y axis and not counts:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want a histogram grouped by ranting for each day? like `cumsum(rating)`?

Comment: @Masoud yes exactly that's what i am looking for

Comment: `library(dplyr);editeddata <- yourdata %>% group_by(date, rating) %>% summarise(n=n())` `library(ggplot2);ggplot(editeddata, aes(x = date, y = n, fill = rating)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')`

Comment: it didn't gives me the plot i want :/ what i'm looking for is a plot having 5 lines where each line represent a rating (1..5), however you're suggesting gives me only bars with ratings degree as key

Comment: Can you speak the standard terms. What do you mean by line? I dunno what's a continuous histogram. Meanwhile I updated my answer to see if that fits your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to get the desired dataset and pass that into `ggplot()`;

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

 sample_data %>% group_by(rating,date) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>%
                ggplot(aes(x=date, y=n, group=rating, color=as.factor(rating))) +
                          geom_line(size=1.5) + geom_point()
```

[image]

***Data:***

```
sample_data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 1L,           
     2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), date = structure(c(1L, 
     1L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L,                 
     6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("2017-11-24", "2017-11-25",             
     "2017-11-26", "2017-11-27", "2017-11-28", "2017-11-29", "2017-12-02",           
     "2017-12-04", "2017-12-08"), class = "factor"), rating = c(1L,                  
     1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L,                 
     1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L), reviews = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,                  
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,                 
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "review", class = "factor")), .Names = c("id",    
     "date", "rating", "reviews"), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: yeah i see what you propose what i am looking for is lines and not bars

Comment: @saul Maybe this `geom_line(aes(fill = as.factor(rating)))` instead of `geom_bar()` would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just using some dummy data:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  set.seed(999)
  df <- data.frame(date = sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/04/01'), by="day"), 2000, replace = T),
             rating = sample(1:5,2000,replace = T))
  df$rating <- as.factor(df$rating)

  df %>%
  group_by(date,rating) %>%
  summarise(n = length(rating)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date,n, color = rating)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: it is giving me the plot with bars, but i want to be a continuous one with geom_line()

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand ;). But you still want different grouping (such as different colors) for each rating or just the total number of reviews received for each date?

Comment: yes i want to plot 5 lines each line represent the evolution of the rating count by date like in this picture `http://dhmontgomery.com/figure/dogrates/plot4-1.png` only instead of average i want the count of rating